# Severe problems on getting to work jedi vim (windows)

Tags: jedi-vim

i have already read a lot of threads with similar topics and the tag jedi-vim here on stackoverflow and also other pages.
But this problem still keeps me from doing my actual work :-/.
Up to now I have already tried several steps back and forth, but basically I did the following:
 1. Install latest Python3.4 (32bit)
 2. Got this precompiled VIM: 
(https:// bitbucket.org/Haroogan/vim-for-windows/downloads/vim-7.4.417-python-2.7-python-3.4-ruby-2.0.0-lua-5.2-perl-5.18-windows-x86.zip) (32Bit)
 3. Installed Pathogen 
 4. Installed Flake8 successfully 
 5. Installed Jedi (systemwide?) with pip 
 6. Got Jedi-vim from github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim and unpacked the dir jedi-vim-master to: 
     6.1. $HOME/vimfiles/bundle/ only 
     6.2. $VIM/vimfiles/bundle/ only 
     6.3. BOTH

python and python3 both work (before I ONLY had python3).
So 
":python3 import sys; print(sys.version)" and 
":python2 import sys; print(sys.version)" give an output.
In my vimrc I force jedi-vim to use python3:
"let g:jedi#force_py_version = 3"

And now the actual error is the following:
When I type e.g. "self." in a *.py-file he searches for half a sec and says:
 
    E117: unknown function: pythoncomplete#Complete
    -- Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found

When I want to call a function and want type the parameters, something pops up / gets faded in, but it's some unclear signs and not the actual parameters.
[see here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwb4EPY-atMdUkZzVmZ6bGJrUDQ/view)

Other info:
:scriptnames :
    D:\tools\v\plugin\getscriptPlugin.vim 
    D:\tools\v\plugin\gzip.vim 
    D:\tools\v\plugin\matchparen.vim 
    D:\tools\v\plugin\netrwPlugin.vim 
    D:\tools\v\plugin\rrhelper.vim 
    D:\tools\v\plugin\spellfile.vim 
    D:\tools\v\plugin\tarPlugin.vim 
    D:\tools\v\plugin\tohtml.vim 
    D:\tools\v\plugin\vimballPlugin.vim 
    D:\tools\v\plugin\zipPlugin.vim 
    D:\tools\v\menu.vim 
    D:\tools\v\lang\menu_de.latin1.vim 
    D:\tools\v\lang\menu_de_de.latin1.vim 
    D:\tools\v\autoload\paste.vim 
    D:\tools\v_gvimrc 
    D:\tools\v\syntax\syntax.vim 
    D:\tools\v\syntax\synload.vim 
    D:\tools\v\syntax\syncolor.vim 
    D:\tools\v\filetype.vim 
    H:\vimfiles\autoload\pathogen.vim 
    D:\tools\v\ftoff.vim 
    D:\tools\v\syntax\nosyntax.vim 
    D:\tools\v\ftplugin.vim 
    D:\tools\v\indent.vim 
    D:\tools\v\syntax\python.vim 
    D:\tools\v\ftplugin\python.vim 
    D:\tools\v\bundle\jedi-vim-master\ftplugin\python\jedi.vim 
    D:\tools\v\bundle\jedi-vim-master\autoload\jedi.vim 
    D:\tools\v\bundle\vim-flake8-master\ftplugin\python_flake8.vim 
    H:\vimfiles\bundle\vim-flake8-master\ftplugin\python_flake8.vim 
    D:\tools\v\indent\python.vim

My vimrc:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwb4EPY-atMdOWhnOGJiNmxYbGM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the jedi-vim completion function is never called.

The error message is about `pythoncomplete#Complete`, which is VIM's default, but it should be set to `:set omnifunc=jedi#completions`.

I feel like the last line in `scriptnames` (`D:\tools\v\indent\python.vim`) overwrites `omnifunc`. Don't know why and how it happens, but that's my gut feeling.

Comment: Ok, this already helps me a lot!
But deleting "D:..\indent\python.vim" does not solve the problem. And deleting "H:..8-master\ftplugin\python_flake8.vim" and "D:..8-master\ftplugin\python_flake8.vim" (all 3)does not help either.
(and having the sideeffect too that my flake8 wont work).

Of course adding the line :set omnifunc=jedi#completions to my vimrc (or for me _gvimrc) (I tried adding it it in the beginning AND in the end) does not help either.
The "unclean" way of starting vim ALWAYS with a script containing this line doesnt work either.
So I will have to start within vim all the time:-/